# Is there a programmatic way to tell if an Excel sheet is corrupt?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have an old and pretty big excel sheet.  It gets saved each day multiple times and it seems like once a week the sheet gets corrupted.

Environment:

- Everyone uses the x64 build of office
- it uses multiple plugins, including Bloomberg and an in house plugin
- it uses multiple RTD's including Bloomberg and an in house one
- we are using the latest version of Office and Excel
- mixture of Win7 and Win10 machines( also x64).

Is there a programmatic way we can tell if a saved excel sheet is corrupt without loading it an manually inspecting that it works fine?

Most(all?) of the time when its corrupt it won't open at all or it will crash when you do something like `CRTL-F`.

We save the sheet multiple times a day and we'd like to verify each save if we could.

Comment: Two free tools can be found from the article
[Excel Workbook Corruption Detection & Recovery](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-diagnose-excel-file-corruption-and-repair-workbooks.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally suggest writing a powershell script.

Below is a basic example of how to open all spreadsheets on the desktop.

If the file is ok/openable the script will output the name of the 1st sheet on the spreadsheet.

If the file is corrupt/unopenable, powershell will throw an exception.

This could easily be extended to give the name of the file and a status in a table.

```
$user = $env:USERNAME
$Location = "c:\users\$user\desktop\"

$ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Location -Filter *.xls*

Foreach ($ExcelFile in $ExcelFiles){
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile.FullName)
    $workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
    $WorkSheet.Name
}
```

This being said, inspecting the issues with the spreadsheet itself would also be a good idea.

Things I have noticed to cause problems with large spreadsheets is a lot of custom formatting throughout the spreadsheet (Different fonts, Coloured text etc).

It may be worth considering starting a new spreadsheet and collaborating the information of the 2 in another if required?

Hope this helps.